# Como llamar de forma correcta una función recursiva python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Me proponen un problema:
Un barco puede navegar por tres días consecutivos, avanzando "a" millas  náuticas,  pero  luego  debe  apagar  máquinas  y  realizar  reparaciones durante  un  día.  En  ese  lapso,  las  corrientes  marinas  alejan  al  barco  de  rescate "b" millas náuticas del punto de destino. Considere que el punto de destino se encuentra a "c" millas

input.txt:

```
"500 80 19000\n
240 40 59003\n 
10 20 80"
```

Construir dos funciones, una iterativa y otra recursiva, que calculen cuántos días tarda el barco en alcanzar el destino, si no lo logra llegar al destino debe imprimir -1

```
def funcion_leer_archivo(entrada):
    datos = []
    with open(entrada, "r") as f:
        for lineas in f:
            datos.append(lineas.split())
    return datos



def funcion_iterativa(archivo):
    i = 0
    while i < len(archivo):
        a,b,c = archivo[i]
        funcion_recursiva(a,b,c)      
        i += 1



def funcion_recursiva(a,b,c):
    dias = 0
    distancia_restante = int(c) - int(a)
    dias += 3
    distancia_restante = distancia_restante + int(b)
    if distancia_restante != 0:
        funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante)
    else:
        print(distancia_restante)
    return distancia_restante

    
archivo = funcion_leer_archivo("input.txt")
funcion_iterativa(archivo)
```

pero obtengo un error y no sé como solucionarlo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "archivo.py", line 44, in <module>
    funcion_iterativa(funcion_leer_archivo("input.txt"))
  File "archivo.py", line 28, in funcion_iterativa
    funcion_recursiva(a,b,c)
  File "archivo.py", line 39, in funcion_recursiva
    funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante)
  File "archivo.py", line 39, in funcion_recursiva
    funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante)
  File "archivo.py", line 39, in funcion_recursiva
    funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante)
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
  File "archivo.py", line 35, in funcion_recursiva
    distancia_restante = int(c) - int(a)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: No debes usar recursión para resolver problemas iterativos.

Comment: Y como debería resolverlo? @CandidMoe

Comment: Podría darte una solución iterativa, pero no es lo que estas preguntado.

Comment: Además de lo que ya ha dicho CandidMoe, en tu caso la función recursiva falla porque no llega a terminar ya que la distancia_restante nunca es igual a 0 (puede ser en algunos casos pero por casualidad) Prueba con >=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente porque nunca se cumple la condición en tu iteración recursiva. Entonces nunca sale de su ciclo

Tu condición para que itere es que sea `distancia_recorrida != 0`.

para esto, distancia recorrida tienes que es

```
    distancia_restante = int(c) - int(a)
    dias += 3
    distancia_restante = distancia_restante + int(b)
```

En el primer caso podemos sustituir.

```
Día | distancia recorrida | distancia faltante | distancia retrasada | distancia total
0.  | 200                 | 1300               | 67                  | 1367
3.  | 200                 | 1167               | 67                  | 1234
6.  | 200                 | 1034               | 67                  | 1101
9.  | 200                 | 901                | 67                  | 968
12  | 200                 | 768                | 67                  | 835
15  | 200                 | 635                | 67                  | 702
18  | 200                 | 502                | 67                  | 569
18  | 200                 | 502                | 67                  | 569
21  | 200                 | 369                | 67                  | 436
24  | 200                 | 236                | 67                  | 303
27  | 200                 | 103                | 67                  | 170
30  | 200                 | -30                | 67                  | 37
```

Como puedes notar, en el día 30 el barco ya se paso la distancia pero nunca queda exacta con el 0

Es por eso que la condición != 0 siempre se cumple y nunca deja de iterar

para solucionarlo simplemente puedes poner

```
distancia_recorrida <= 0
```

esto no aplica para el último caso que cada vez se aleja más, aquí iterará nuevamente sin límites y será el mismo error.

Para esto simplemente puedes validar que la distancia se acorte con al condición

```
if distancia_recorrida < c:
    return -1
```

Aquí lo puedes poner encima de tu primera validación para que si la distancia ahora es mayor que la distancia inicial, ya no siga iterando. Quedando tu función así

```
def funcion_recursiva(a,b,c):
    dias = 0
    distancia_restante = int(c) - int(a)
    dias += 3
    distancia_restante = distancia_restante + int(b)
    if distancia_restante < c:
        return -1
    elif distancia_restante <= 0:
        funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante)
    else:
        print(distancia_restante)
    return distancia_restante
```

Aquí falta ajustar en qué momento regresar qué cada cosa pero la idea es la misma

Comment: `función_recursiva` retorna `distancia_restante`, pero cuando la llamas, no ocupas ese valor. Algo sobra o algo falta por ahi.

Comment: Era distancia restante la variable, gracias por la observación

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar vamos a meter los días también en la función recursiva ya que van a ir cambiando cada vez que se ejecute la función:

```
def funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante,dias=1):
```

También hay que tener en cuenta el caso en el que el Barco `b` va más rápido que `a` y nunca será alcanzado:

```
if b>a: #Nunca alcanzará al barco
    return -1
```

El barco `a` avanza tres días pero el día 4 tiene que quedarse parado, y el barco `b` se aleja (aquí no tengo muy claro si solamente se aleja ese día, por el enunciado entiendo que lo que se aleja el resto de días ya está contemplado en `a`), así que los días en los que se queda parado serían:

1 2 3 **4** 5 6 7 **8** 9 10 11 **12** 13 14 15 **16** 17...

Es decir los múltiplos de 4. Por lo que esos días la `distancia_restante` aumentará `b` y el resto de días disminuirá `a`.

```
    if dias % 4 == 0:
        return funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante +b, dias +1)
    else:
        return funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante -a, dias +1)
```

Ya solo quedaría evitar que se ejecute eternamente, por lo que la distancia debe ser superior 0 y si es inferior o igual es que ese día hemos alcanzado al barco `b`.

```
def funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante, dias=1):
    if b>a: #Nunca alcanzará al barco
        return -1
    if distancia_restante > 0:
        if dias % 4 == 0:
            return funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante +b, dias +1)
        else:
            return funcion_recursiva(a, b, distancia_restante -a, dias +1)
    else:
        return dias
```

Con esto en alguno de tus ejemplos obtenemos:

```
print(funcion_recursiva(200, 67, 15000)) #Devuelve 114
print(funcion_recursiva(30, 40, 60)) #Devuelve -1
```